# Bootstrap 4 nav bar items text wrapping issue

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image]

**Hi I want the links words should be in the same like not wrap to the down like this.**

This is what I have done.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Vacation.com</a>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggler="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Beaches / Resorts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Sailing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

**How do I do that in Bootstrap?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text-nowrap` on the links...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Vacation.com</a>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggler="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-nowrap">Beaches / Resorts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-nowrap">Sailing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-nowrap">Contact us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```